# I want to make these images clickable to separate pages see JS code

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink

```html
<!--my images appear here but they are not clickable-->

<div class="image-container">
       <span id="result" align="center"></span> 
</div>
```

I need to add separate links to the images I've tried all kinds see my code, I want to add a link to the image links,

```
<script>
        var dd = 5;
        var cnt = 0;
        function chng() {

            var rotator = document.getElementById('stars');  
            var imageDir = 'images/'; 
            // see the images below I need links adding so they can be clicked                            
            var images = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png'];

            cnt++;

            var len = images.length;
            if (cnt < dd) {
                stars.src = imageDir + images[cnt];
            }
            else if (cnt == len) {
                stars.src = imageDir + images[0];
                cnt = 0;
            }
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Do you have an `<img>` element with the ID "rr"? Where/how do you call the `chng()` function? What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with separate links? Can you share a more complete example along with the HTML you are changing, and what HTML structure you're looking for?

Comment: @JockStrap check my answer. Is it that what you want?

Comment: I need the images '1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png' to be clickable